# C# using hidden webbrowser control to get content of page

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Hy,

I'm using the webbrowser control to get some content of a page and use that in the program (C#).

When I've got the webbrowser visible (this.webBrowser1.Visible = true;) the program just runs fine, but when i set the value to false (this.webBrowser1.Visible = false;), I get errors on this part of code:

```
HtmlWindow SContentFrame = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[1];
HtmlWindow Frame_A = SContentFrame.Document.Window.Frames[2];
HtmlElementCollection bigFontTags = Frame_A.Document.GetElementsByTagName("b");
```

Do I need to select the webbrowser or something like that??? or is there an another problem? Because when the webbrowser controller is visible, this piece of code works, but when I hide the webbrowser, it doesn't work at all...

Any thoughts would be appreciated....

TWCrap

Comment: First things first: are you sure you really need a webbrowser control? Did you consider using, for example, the [HTML Agilitiy pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)?

Comment: not yet, because i've haven't heard of it before, but i will look at it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple trick is to hide the browser ofset on your form, so if your width of your form is for example 300 px you place the left of the browser on 350

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are approaching this the wrong way.

The webbrowser is not meant to be used in this way, why not just download the contents of the webpage in the background using WebClient for example? This has a much lower overhead than the WebBrowser.

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) is very useful if you are working on a scraping type application.

Comment: But there's only one problem on the webpage... There using iframes, and you need to log in, and then the source of the iframe changes to show the content. And when you re-enter the url (or press F5), you need to log in again... Can The HTML Agility Pack handle this right???

Comment: What about rendering html with javascript, even with javascript callbacks to make it somewhat smoother than waiting arbitrary time. You need a WebBrowser for that right? Just getting the HTML (including static javascript) of a page is not enough if the javascript is designed to manipulate the DOM.